# Google nearby between IOS and android

Tags: android, ios, google-nearby

I recently heard about google nearby API, which supports both IOS and Android. I want to create a chat app. I want to know weather can I use this nearby api to create an app which chat between an android and IOS device (platform independent). Does this google nearby thing have this feature in it! Is that possible by any way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'nearby messages' api is available for iOS. Just to mention it requires internet connection to establish connection. 'Nearby connection' api on the other hand serves offline. I don't think google has yet released 'nearby connection' api for iOS

Comment: Is there any solution available that allows connect and share small amount of data between Android and iOS offline (When internet not available) and online (When internet is available) both of case. Actually I am looking for the solution for both android and iOS and also with online and offline. Any suggestion / idea/ code ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Nearby on both Android and iOS and yes, it works fine. We're having trouble getting the iOS app through Apple's review process - they don't like the use of the mic even though we don't use it explicitly, although the library does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can see some sample codes [here](https://github.com/ulternate/nearby-chat)